# How to disable shadows in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I'm trying to disable shadows in Cycles for the purpose of using decals, since shadows break the illusion and make it an evident sticker. I've tried setting shadow mode to "none" in material proiperties tab and in object properties in Ray Visibility, turned off shadows. Now, while in evee looks fine in Cycles the decal still casts shadows. I k now that I can use a second UV to implant the decal in the material itself but when using Subd-modeling it causes unavoidable stretching.

So, is there a way to turn off shadows so as to use decals attached with shrinkwrap not making itself apparent with a shadow, no matter how small?

Comment: You say that in Cycles the decal still casts shadows, it should not if you've disabled Ray VIsibility > Shadow, so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I got to the bottom of it. When I turned off shadows from object properties it seemed to still cast a fenter "shadow" except it wasnt a sahdow, but reflection so I turned off glossy too and that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your decal Object level Properties, in *Ray Visibility* disble Shadow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying!. The fainter "shadow" I kept seeing after turning off shadows was actually a reflection so turning off Glossy was also needed in this case (it was a decently reflective material).

Comment: @Andermaiden You just have to be aware that turning off _Shadow_ and _Glossy_ might result in problems when interacting with other objects surrounding the decal. For example, the decal becomes invisible in other reflective objects (e.g. like a mirror): [no reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO6gB.jpg). But as you might see, not completely invisible: the remaining comes from _Diffuse_ visibility. But if you turn that off as well, not even completely diffuse surfaces like the plane here will get any colored bounce light: [no diffuse bounces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvRF3.jpg)

Comment: Oh, then which would be the right way to go abut with decals? Because games are using them now so there must be a way.

Comment: @Andermaiden if you want Gordon to get a notice of your followup question, you should use the *@* notation "@GordonBrinkmann", otherwise he will not see it.  I'm afraid I cannot answer your question myself.