How to remove shadows between two transparent objects
I have an asset for a cross road (as well as others with the same problem). The asphalt section is one mesh and the lines are another.
In rendered view, the proximity of the two faces are so close, it generates a black shadow between the two objects.
So what can I do to fix this.
I appreciate your responses.
Here's what it looks like when it's together

And when it's separated


Do they have to be separate objects? You can mix textures within a material by Alpha channels... what happens there when they are close together is not a shadow, but most likely Z-fighting. That is when two faces are lying in the same plane and the render engine cannot decide on which face should be rendered in front of the other. So the main fix would be leaving a little gap between them or use a single material and object.

Thanks for the comment but it's not z fighting. It's actually a shadow. And they're actually on the same mesh, just separate parts of the same mesh. Asphalt material on one part and paint material on the other. But when I bring them close to one another, the transparent parts of the paint material show up as a shadow. I also tried increasing light bounces in the light path section for transparent materials, but the result didn't change.. I could disable the shadow casting of the mesh entirely, but I'm guessing there is a solution in the shading workspace I'm not aware of yet.

Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300425/how-to-disable-shadows-in-cycles ?

Is It Cycles or EEVEE?

@Default_dx Well, if it is not Z-fighting and really some kind of shadow it is a bit hard to understand why this shadow only appears when they are so close together, shadows should usually be visible with some distance too (or is the shadow gradually getting fuzzier when increasing the distance and just seems to be gone?). About same or separate mesh: what I meant is why are they separate parts with two materials? Just use the asphalt mesh part and create the paint part within the material, then this problem would not exist. Unless you need them to be separate parts.

@Crantisz In his comment he says he tried increasing the bounces for transparency in the Light Paths section... these settings do not exist in Eevee, only in Cycles. But of course I cannot rule out he tried switching engines, but then he probably mentioned if the issue was present in both or only one of them.
